# Load declaration must be compatible with ...FixtureInterface::load()

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am creating a Doctrine data fixture that needs a load function. I literal copied the method from FixtureInterface.php but somehow the load() of my fixture differs.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of PastonVerBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadTimeZoneData::load() must be compatible with that of Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface::load() in /var/www/symfony/src/Paston/VerBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/LoadTimeZoneData.php on line 9
```

My load:

```
<?php

namespace PastonVerBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Paston\VerBundle\Entity\TimeZone;

class LoadTimeZoneData 
    implements FixtureInterface {

    function load(ObjectManager $manager) {

        $z = new \TimeZone();
        $z->setName('Timezone');
        $manager->persist($z);
        $manager->flush();
    }

}

?>
```

Load from FixtureInterface.php

```
namespace Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

/**
 * Interface contract for fixture classes to implement.
 *
 * @author Jonathan H. Wage <jonwage@gmail.com>
 */
interface FixtureInterface
{
    /**
     * Load data fixtures with the passed EntityManager
     *
     * @param Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager $manager
     */
    function load(ObjectManager $manager);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing `use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;`:

```
namespace PastonVerBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Paston\VerBundle\Entity\TimeZone;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class LoadTimeZoneData 
    implements FixtureInterface {

    function load(ObjectManager $manager) {

        $z = new \TimeZone();
        $z->setName('Timezone');
        $manager->persist($z);
        $manager->flush();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message but with OrderedFixture interface
not with FixtureInterface itelf.

In my case it was nothing related to load() method indeed.
In the real fact I had omitted to add the method getOrder() which is
mandatory in the interface.

Thus, this error message led me to a wrong hint. So beware of it sometimes :)